# My View works fine for my Desktop but doesn't work right for my mobile

Tags: css, xml, sapui5

Hello some one can help me to fix this ?
In my Desktop browser my fragment view works fine  but in my mobile it doesn't...

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76GbN.png)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEI2W.png)

this is my View :

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:custom="meusapps.testeAppOpenUI5.control">
<ScrollContainer id="root1" horizontal="false" vertical="true" height="100%">
    <List id="listaProposta" headerText="Propostas em Tramitação" items="{ path: 'modelProposta>/'}">
        <CustomListItem >
            <HBox  width="100%">
                <HBox width="75%">
                    <HBox alignContent="Center" alignItems="Center">
                        <Avatar src="{modelProposta>detalheAutores/ultimoStatus/urlFoto}" initials="{modelProposta>initials}" displaySize="M" showBorder="true"
                            class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom"/>
                    </HBox>
                    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
                        <Label text="{modelProposta>proposta/siglaTipo} {modelProposta>proposta/numero}/{modelProposta>proposta/ano}" design="Bold" wrapping="true"/>
                        <Label text="{modelProposta>proposta/ementa}" wrapping="true"/>
                    </VBox>
                </HBox>
                <HBox width="25%">
                    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
                        <HBox alignContent="Center" alignItems="Center" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom">
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://thumb-up" type="Accept" press="onAgreePress" class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiMediumMarginEnd roundButton"/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://thumb-down" type="Reject" press="onDisagreePress" class="sapUiMediumMarginEnd roundButton"/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://decline" press="onRemovePress" class="roundButton"/>
                        </HBox>
                        <custom:Rating id="pi-with-animation" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom sapUiSizeCompact" percentValue="50" displayValue="50%" state="Success"
                             displayOnly="true"/>
                    </VBox>
                </HBox>
            </HBox>
        </CustomListItem>
    </List>
</ScrollContainer>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Use Media Queries?

Comment: Dunno sapui5, but it seems that `<HBox  width="100%">` needs to become a `<VBox>` in mobile mode so the rating can wrap below the text

Comment: Weill the mobile view looks exactly like you programmed it. 75/25. Have you tried a responsive table? Column 1: Avatar / Column 2: Text / Colum  3: Rating. Then you can set `demandPopin="true"` for your third column to move it below the text on mobile devices.

Comment: @Marc i will try it ...

Comment: @Marc it's worked !  but my popin doesn't be align at the center. Looks very strange because my buttons it's align on the right

Comment: Doesn't matter ... i found a solution about this !
Thanks @Marc for you advice

Comment: If the solution might be helpful to others I suggest sharing it. You can answer your own questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem following the advice of @Marc, I changed the control CustomListItem to ResponsiveTable  and used the popin  for the third column